# Can you still use a troop camp whilst upgrading it?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I am upgrading a camp, does it freeze it or can I still use it during the upgrade?  I upgraded my spell bowl not realizing I couldn’t use it, so want to be sure before I do the upgrade.

Comment: Army camps and storages are useable during upgrade. If they wern't, where would the extra gold or troops go?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Personal experience tells me that yes you can still use them and the [wiki](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Army_Camp/Home_Village) also states the following:

> They continue to function even when they are being upgraded, allowing you to keep your armies at full capacity at all times.